# On the CFL condition in upwind method for systems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

> The upwind scheme for system of equations $$U_t + A U_x = 0$$ where $$ U =\begin{pmatrix} u_1\\ u_2 \end{pmatrix}\qquad  A =\begin{pmatrix} 2 &1\\ 1 &2 \end{pmatrix}$$ is $$ \frac{U_j^{n+1} - U_j^{n}}{\Delta t} +  A^+ \frac{U_{j}^n - U_{j-1}^n}{\Delta x} + A^-\frac{U_{j+1}^n - U_j^{n}}{\Delta x} =0$$ Find $A^+$ and $A^-$. For given $\Delta t$, find the minimum $\Delta x$ so that the CFL condition can be satisfied. What kind of boundary condition must be given to solve this problem?

Im trying to understand how this differs from the scalar $u_t + a u_x = 0$ case. We need to put it in the form

$$ U_j^{n+1} = U_{j}^n + \nu ( F(U) ) $$

where $\nu = \frac{A \Delta t }{\Delta x} $. So, are they asking to infer $A^+$ and $A^-$ so that the scheme is conservative? How do we do this?

Comment: In this case, the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are your wave speeds (analogous to $a$ in the scalar case). The computational scheme takes the average of the forward and backward differences for the spatial derivative, so after going through some algebra you can find the (I believe diagonal) matrix $d$ such that  $A^+=A+d$ and $A^-=A-d$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce the following diagonalization of $A = R \Lambda R^{-1}$:
$$
R = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} ,
\qquad
\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} ,
\qquad
R^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} ,
$$
and consider $V = R^{-1}U$. We have two independent scalar advection equation for the coordinates of $V$, since $V$ satisfies the diagonal system $V_t +\Lambda V_x = 0$.
Here, both eigenvalues of $A$ are positive, so that the same upwind direction is chosen for both advection equations. Going back to the original variables $U$, we therefore have $A^+=A$ and $A^-=0$. For general linear hyperbolic systems of conservation laws, the same methodology leads to choosing $A^+$ and $A^-$ as follows:
$$
A^\pm = \tfrac12 (A\pm |A|),
\qquad
|A| = R |\Lambda| R^{-1} .
$$
The Courant number $\text{Co}$ is defined with respect to the largest absolute value of the eigenvalues of $A$. Therefore, the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy condition writes as $$\text{Co} = 3 \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} \leq 1 $$
in the present case.